# How to write a schema for creating a table for the below data which has only one column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, schema

```
[c3f36c25-2546-48b2-bd72-1b5e5dcae2ab, 1620247529, 6032, Amoma, 17256, false, Tui.com, 17149, false]
```

```
c3f36c25-2546-48b2-bd72-1b5e5dcae2a- userid
1620247529- timestamp
6032-parkid
Amoma-parkname
17256-cost
false -dinner
```

here .. park id is the maptype which includes amoma,mercury
amoma is the array type which includes cost and dinner .. Need to write the schema for this

Comment: what kind of value ```parkid``` can have ?? can you give some sample value for parkid & Amoma

Comment: parkid holds the numbers like 6032,5432,3245         Amoma is the parkname which is string .. values are amoma,mercury,venus..

Comment: parkid is map type you have given single values, what about other values ??

Comment: [c3f36c25-2546-48b2-bd72-1b5e5dcae2ab, 1620247529, 6032, Amoma, 17256, false, Tui.com, 17149, false, 39448, false, 8001, expedia, 34650, false, Mercure, 21490, false, Destinia, 13719, false, 23011, false, 9788, false, Tui.com, 25723, false, booking.com, 29272, false, 28400, false, 6033, Amoma, 5361, false, Destinia, 17847]   i need to create a dataframe for the above data

Comment: The data contains only one column .. i feel that is the problem needs to be sorted out

Comment: @srinivas: did u get the question ..please let me know for clarification

Comment: You have given data csv, I am not able to figure which column value goes to where ?, please add multiple rows & add each value to column name

Comment: I have the dat file . i used the below spark commands for splitting the data and make it as ASCII free data .please find the spark scala code and the output below                                         val df = rawDF.map((s:String) => (s.split("['\u0001','\u0002','\u0003','\u0004',\u0005','\u0006','\u0007','\u0008',\u0009,\u0010]"))).toDF()                                         /ouput data is the same which i pasted above . Since this data has map and array types which i mentioned above . we need to write a schema for this . @srinivas :Please let me know for any clarifications

Comment: can you create case class whatever columns you now ??

Comment: val sschema = new StructType()
      .add("userid",StringType)
      .add("unix_time",StringType)
   .add("advertisers", MapType(StringType,ArrayType(new StructType().add("eurocents", IntegerType).add("breakfast", BooleanType))))    -- this is working but i am getting null vaues in the ouput

Comment: i tried with case class also                                                                                                                       case class Record(userid: String,unix_time:String, advertiser:String,euroCents:Int,breakfast:Boolean)

Comment: I have checked your data, its completely flatten there is no difference to identify map or list. i think in this case whatever schema I gave below will not work. You just have to read  column by column add that value to below classes.

Comment: @srinivas : Thanks for ur reply .  I am trying the other way .. df3.withColumn("userid", $"value".getItem(0))
//   .withColumn("timestamp", $"value".getItem(1)).   is there any way to get the map and array columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below schema & if not working add some more sample data.

```
scala> case class Advertise(eurocents: Int,breakfast: Boolean)
defined class Advertise

scala> case class Advertisers(advertisers:Map[String,Seq[Advertise]])
defined class Advertisers

scala> case class Record(userId: String,unix_time: String,parkid:Map[String,Advertisers])
defined class Record

scala> val schema = Encoders.product[Record].schema
schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(userId,StringType,true), StructField(unix_time,StringType,true), StructField(parkid,MapType(StringType,StructType(StructField(advertisers,MapType(StringType,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(eurocents,IntegerType,false), StructField(breakfast,BooleanType,false)),true),true),true)),true),true))
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215406/discussion-on-answer-by-srinivas-how-to-write-a-schema-for-creating-a-table-for).